# C# - Shoot only once - IsKeyUp & IsKeyDown

Tags: c#, if-statement, xna

I have been a problem with my Shoot Em Up game for a while now and I really can't seem to find any answers. I want to only shoot 1 bullet even though I'm holding down the spacebar. With my current code I don't fire any bullets at all. What am I doing wrong?

```
        KeyboardState newState = Keyboard.GetState();
        KeyboardState oldState = Keyboard.GetState();

        if (oldState.IsKeyUp(Keys.Space) && newState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Space))
        {
            bulletList.Add(new Bullet(content.Load<Texture2D>(@"bullet"), new Vector2(initialPos.X, initialPos.Y - 28), new Vector2(2, 4), spriteBatch));
        }

        oldState = newState;
```

Comment: [Here is the example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb203902.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are checking to see if the spacebar is both up and down, which is impossible. I think you should try something like this:

```
bool readytofire = true;
public override void Update()
{
    KeyboardState newState = Keyboard.GetState();

    readytofire = !newState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Space);

    if (newState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Space) && readytofire)
    {
        bulletList.Add(new Bullet(content.Load<Texture2D>(@"bullet"), new Vector2(initialPos.X, initialPos.Y - 28), new Vector2(2, 4), spriteBatch));
    }
}
```

Comment: sure, glad it helped. I just realized that the `readytofire` should be updated before the if...then statement (so if the spacebar is up the `readytofire` will be true that update call)

Comment: This is an interesting way to do it, although all the op had to do was define the oldState outside of the loop and then assign it only if it is null. if(oldState == null) oldState = Keyboard.GetState(); Then the rest of his code would be fine

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the old state right before checking it, so it will always be the same as newState.  Remove this line:
`KeyboardState oldState = Keyboard.GetState();`

You may need to assign a value to oldState for the first time it runs through your loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
KeyboardState newState = Keyboard.GetState();
KeyboardState oldState = Keyboard.GetState();
```

These will have the same value.

```
if (oldState.IsKeyUp(Keys.Space) && newState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Space))
```

This is checking that the Space key is both UP and DOWN.

Both code fragments don't make sense. Is this code inside a loop? If so, check for space DOWN and use a boolean flag to make sure you fire only once. Then check for space UP, reversing the flag.